# tableview data not showing properly in swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, swift3, swift2

[image]

Tableview with three checkbox[in,out,absent] if click any one check box[in,out,absent] it's call the Json service
 and display the data in tableview all are working fine except [Out] checkbox.if I click the [out] checkbox result at out label like [outlabel:11:54 PM] has to show. it's showing empty
at [outlabelg:  ], if I click next cell [out checkbox] in tableview updated the privieous [out:Labledata] data and present selected cell [out:lable]data . pls help me where I did mistake

this is tableview code

```
func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {

    return (attendanceInfo.count == 0) ? 0 : 1

}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return attendanceInfo.count

}


func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell =
        tableView.dequeueReusableCell(
            withIdentifier: "DetailsCell", for: indexPath) as! AttendanceDetailsTableViewCell

    let row = (indexPath as NSIndexPath).row


    cell.InButton.tag = row

    cell.OutButton.tag = row

    cell.AbsentButton.tag = row

    let maskLayer = CAShapeLayer()

    let bounds = cell.bounds

    maskLayer.path = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: CGRect(x: 5, y: 3, width: bounds.width-15, height: bounds.height-15), cornerRadius: 2).cgPath
    cell.layer.mask = maskLayer


    if(attendanceInfo.count>0){

        let attendance = attendanceInfo[row] as AttendanceInfo

       cell.AttendnceLabel.textColor = UIColor(red: CGFloat(0x00)/255
            ,green: CGFloat(0xB1)/255
            ,blue: CGFloat(0xB1)/255
            ,alpha: 1.0)

        cell.AbsentInfoLabel.isHidden = true

        cell.Absentinfovalue.isHidden = true


        if(attendance.inTime == "")&&(attendance.outTime == "")
        {


            cell.InButton.isHidden = false
            cell.OutButton.isHidden = true
            cell.AbsentButton.isHidden = true
            cell.OutinfoLabel.isHidden = false


        }

        if(attendance.inTime != "")
        {


            cell.InButton.isHidden = true
            cell.OutButton.isHidden = false
            cell.AbsentButton.isHidden = false
            cell.OutinfoLabel.isHidden = false

        }

        if(attendance.inTime != "") && (attendance.outTime != "")
        {

            cell.InButton.isHidden = true
            cell.OutButton.isHidden = true
            cell.AbsentButton.isHidden = true
            cell.OutinfoLabel.isHidden = false
            cell.OutLable.text = attendance.outTime

        }

        if(attendance.attendance == "PRESENT")

        {
            cell.OutLable.text = attendance.outTime



        }

        if(attendance.attendance == "ABSENT")
        {
            cell.InButton.isHidden = true
            cell.OutButton.isHidden = true
            cell.AbsentButton.isHidden = true

            cell.Absentinfovalue.isHidden = false
            cell.OutLable.isHidden = true
            cell.OutinfoLabel.isHidden = true

           cell.AttendnceLabel.textColor = UIColor.red
            cell.Absentinfovalue.text = attendance.updatedTime


        }

        cell.Class.text = attendance.standard

        cell.NameLabel.text = attendance.name

        cell.InLabel.text = attendance.inTime

        cell.OutLable.text = attendance.outTime

        cell.AttendnceLabel.text = attendance.attendance

        cell.DateLablel.text = attendance.attendanceDate

        cell.attendanceid = attendance.attendanceId


        cell.backgroundView = UIImageView(image: UIImage(named: "background_common")!)


        cell.Profileimage.image = UIImage(named: "profile_pic")
        cell.Profileimage.downloadImageFrom(link: attendance.photo!, contentMode: UIViewContentMode.scaleAspectFit)


        if(InCheckec[indexPath.row]==true)
        {
            cell.InButton.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(named: "Check_Box"), for: UIControlState.normal)
            cell.InButton.isSelected = true

        }
        else{


            cell.InButton.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(named: "uncheck_Box"), for: UIControlState.normal)
            cell.InButton.isSelected = false
        }

        if(OutCheckec[indexPath.row]==true)
        {
            cell.OutButton.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(named: "Check_Box"), for: UIControlState.normal)
            cell.OutButton.isSelected = true

        }
        else{


            cell.OutButton.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(named: "uncheck_Box"), for: UIControlState.normal)
            cell.OutButton.isSelected = false
        }



        if(AbsentCheckec[indexPath.row]==true)
        {
            cell.AbsentButton.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(named: "Check_Box"), for: UIControlState.normal)
            cell.AbsentButton.isSelected = true

        }
        else{


            cell.AbsentButton.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(named: "uncheck_Box"), for: UIControlState.normal)
            cell.AbsentButton.isSelected = false
        }
    }

    return cell

}
```

this is the code of out check box[in,absent also same like this way of code]

```
@IBAction func OUTBUTTON(_ sender: UIButton) {
    snackbar.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: CGFloat(0x00)/255
        ,green: CGFloat(0xB1)/255
        ,blue: CGFloat(0xB1)/255
        ,alpha: 1.0)


    status = "2"

    let buttontag = sender.tag

    let prefs:UserDefaults = UserDefaults.standard
    StaffID = prefs.value(forKey: "STAFFID") as! String


    let position: CGPoint = sender.convert(CGPoint(x: 10, y: 20), to: self.TableView)
    let indexPath = self.TableView.indexPathForRow(at: position)



    if (sender.isSelected == true)

    {

        OutCheckec[buttontag] = false
        inButtoncount -= 1

        if(inButtoncount == 0)
        {
            snackbar.dismiss()
            upStudentId.removeAll()
            upAttendanceID.removeAll()
            UPstatusTest.removeAll()
        }
        else{

            upStudentId.removeLast()
            UPstatusTest.removeLast()
            upAttendanceID.removeLast()

        }

    }
    else
    {


        OutCheckec[buttontag] = true
        AbsentCheckec[buttontag] = false

        inButtoncount += 1
        snackbar.show()

        let out:Bool = true

        prefs.set(out, forKey:"1")


        let kid = attendanceInfo[(indexPath?.row)!] as AttendanceInfo

        upStudentId.append(kid.studentId!)
        upAttendanceID.append(kid.attendanceId)
        UPstatusTest.append(status)
        upStaffId = StaffID

    }



    self.TableView.reloadRows(at: [indexPath!], with: UITableViewRowAnimation.none)

}
```

this is Json Results 
[image]

Comment: Not related, but `if(attendanceInfo.count>0){` is completely useless. If the array is empty `numberOfRows` returns 0 and `cellForRow` is not called at all.

Comment: Json Data is storing in to the attendanceInfo with out that how can count the students

Comment: I mean this check is meaningless, it will never evaluate to false.

Comment: I can remove that but let attendance = attendanceInfo[row] as AttendanceInfo

Comment: I get this error at row position fatal error: Index out of range

Comment: it's same as previous issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is the working code

```
 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let cell =
            tableView.dequeueReusableCell(
                withIdentifier: "DetailsCell", for: indexPath) as! AttendanceDetailsTableViewCell

        let row = (indexPath as NSIndexPath).row


        cell.InButton.tag = row

        cell.OutButton.tag = row

        cell.AbsentButton.tag = row

        let maskLayer = CAShapeLayer()

        let bounds = cell.bounds

        maskLayer.path = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: CGRect(x: 5, y: 3, width: bounds.width-15, height: bounds.height-15), cornerRadius: 2).cgPath
        cell.layer.mask = maskLayer


        if(attendanceInfo.count>0){

        let attendance = attendanceInfo[row] as AttendanceInfo

           cell.AttendnceLabel.textColor = UIColor(red: CGFloat(0x00)/255
                ,green: CGFloat(0xB1)/255
                ,blue: CGFloat(0xB1)/255
                ,alpha: 1.0)


        if(attendance.inTime == "")&&(attendance.outTime == "")
            {


                cell.InButton.isHidden = false
                cell.OutButton.isHidden = true
                cell.AbsentButton.isHidden = true
            }

            if(attendance.inTime != "")
            {
                cell.InButton.isHidden = true
                cell.OutButton.isHidden = false
                cell.AbsentButton.isHidden = false
            }


            if(attendance.inTime != "") && (attendance.outTime != "")
            {

                cell.InButton.isHidden = true
                cell.OutButton.isHidden = true
                cell.AbsentButton.isHidden = true
                cell.OutLable.text = attendance.outTime

            }
            cell.OutLable.text=" "
            cell.OutinfoLabel.text="Out"

            if(attendance.attendance == "PRESENT")

            {
                cell.OutLable.text = attendance.outTime
                cell.OutinfoLabel.text = "Out"

            }else if(attendance.attendance == "ABSENT")
            {
                cell.InButton.isHidden = true
                cell.OutButton.isHidden = true
                cell.AbsentButton.isHidden = true

                cell.OutinfoLabel.text = "Absent11"
                cell.OutLable.text = attendance.updatedTime
                cell.AttendnceLabel.textColor = UIColor.red

            }


            cell.Class.text = attendance.standard

            cell.NameLabel.text = attendance.name

            cell.InLabel.text = attendance.inTime

            cell.AttendnceLabel.text = attendance.attendance

            cell.DateLablel.text = attendance.attendanceDate

            cell.attendanceid = attendance.attendanceId


            cell.backgroundView = UIImageView(image: UIImage(named: "background_common")!)


            cell.Profileimage.image = UIImage(named: "profile_pic")
            cell.Profileimage.downloadImageFrom(link: attendance.photo!, contentMode: UIViewContentMode.scaleAspectFit)


            if(InCheckec[indexPath.row]==true)
            {
                cell.InButton.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(named: "Check_Box"), for: UIControlState.normal)
                cell.InButton.isSelected = true

            }
            else{


                cell.InButton.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(named: "uncheck_Box"), for: UIControlState.normal)
                cell.InButton.isSelected = false
            }

            if(OutCheckec[indexPath.row]==true)
            {
                cell.OutButton.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(named: "Check_Box"), for: UIControlState.normal)
                cell.OutButton.isSelected = true

            }
            else{


                cell.OutButton.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(named: "uncheck_Box"), for: UIControlState.normal)
                cell.OutButton.isSelected = false
            }



            if(AbsentCheckec[indexPath.row]==true)
            {
                cell.AbsentButton.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(named: "Check_Box"), for: UIControlState.normal)
                cell.AbsentButton.isSelected = true

            }
            else{


                cell.AbsentButton.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(named: "uncheck_Box"), for: UIControlState.normal)
                cell.AbsentButton.isSelected = false
            }
        }

        return cell

    }
```